# PHP: Error handling with include

Tags: php, error-handling, include

```
$file= @fopen("ssssss.php", r) or die("not found");
(@include("ssssss.php")) or die("not found");
```

In the first statement we don't put ( ) around @fopen and it is working fine.
But in the second if I didn't put these () it does't show any message.

so why with include I must round it with ( ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the suggestions in the other answers but the actual answer to your question is this:

In the PHP documentation they say to take care when comparing the return value of include.

That's because it is a special construct and parentheses are not needed.

So when you do this (without wrapping parentheses):

```
@include("ssssss.php") or die("not found");
```

You're actually doing this, because `or` is evaluated first:

```
@include (("ssssss.php") or die("not found"));
```

Now, "ssssss.php" is a non empty string that evaluates logically to true.

`or` is a logical operator that gives true if any of the parameters is true (or both of them).
Also, this operator is short-circuit: if the first parameter is true, php already knows that the operator `or` will return true, so it doesn't waste time evaluating the second parameter, and `die()` is not executed.

So finally, `or` gives true and your sentence becames this:

```
@include (1);
```

Php tries to "include 1", and it would raise a warning but it does not because of the `@`.

Here you have a [similar example in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-125).

---

Your first sentence is not the same case.

```
$file= @fopen("ssssss.php", r) or die("not found");
```

`fopen` is just a regular Php's function with its parentheses. Here you need to have in mind two operators: `=` and `or`.

`=` has [higher precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `or`, so, if fopen's result is correctly assigned to `$file` (and it is), that operation will return true. And, as I explained before, "true `or` anything else", gives true but die() is not executed because of the short-circuit operator.

Comment: many thanks @nanocv. I see now . but why it becomes '@include(1)' ?

Comment: but the same concept can apply to the first code too!! : `$file= @fopen( ("ssssss.php", r) or die("not found") );` but it doesn't !!!

Comment: You're welcome @Mahmoud! I edited my answer to explain your questions in both comments (for the record). Hope it helps!

Comment: that is wonderful. Great answer . I'm so grateful . last question does , "ssssss.php" evaluates logically to true always ?  even this file doesn't exist ? doesn't that seem little weird ?!!

Comment: Yes, always. In that case, php doesn't see a file name, it just sees a string. If you try to do this `if("hello.php")`, the condition gives true always. Strings only evaluate to false when they are empty or "0". Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `file_exists` instead of using the `@` as the later covers all sorts of issues.  A better solution would be...

```
if (file_exists("ssssss.php")) {   
    $file= @fopen("ssssss.php", r);                       
}
```

and

```
if (file_exists("ssssss.php")) {   
   include("ssssss.php");                       
}
```

Comment: thanks Nigel . the 2 statements aren't related at all . they are seperate. the only thing that related is the error handling . that was my question . why I have to use () with include and the other not !

Comment: There are a lot of things in PHP which can be unpredictable and 'odd'.  But using `include` `or die` logic is just bad practice.  IMHO using `die` anywhere is bad practice and you should put more effort into good practice than trying to work out why this is odd.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a good use of include. If you need to include a php file and generate an error on failure, use `require` or `require_once`.

If you need to get the contents of the whole file, you could use `file_get_contents()`.

Also, I agree with Nigel Ren about the use of `@` - it is a dangerous practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I wasn't concern on getting the content of the file. I'm just want to know the difference between the 2 statements in error handling. I noticed that Include use special way so I want to figure the reason behind that